# slight problem with fullcalendar when event has an apostrophe -- it disappears

Tags: mysql, fullcalendar, apostrophe

I am using fullcalendar with a mysql recordset and php. It works really well, but if an event has an apostrophe, the calendar does not appear.

Is there a quick and easy way to escape the apostrophe or strip it from the string automatically ?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't appear? Is this a client side javascript issue or a database issue? Can you show some relevant code?

Comment: If you're having issues with single `'` or double `"` quotes, your script may be vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: What I mean is, if the database field which contains the eventname has a ' character in it, the page displays no calendar at all.
The sql generates the recordset Ok, but the calendar can't deal with the apostrophe. What I have now done , and it seems to work, is in the php code loop, use the addslashes php function with the relevant field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape your apostrophe's with the backslash character '\':

```
$blah = 'nicklamort\'s answer';
```

Comment: thanks, I did this using addslashes() to the relevant recordset field

Comment: nice! :) I couldn't think of the name of that function lol. Is that answer worthy? ^^;